# Django circular import error - how to debug it?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I tried to follow this tutorial
https://blog.nicolasmesa.co/posts/2018/10/saas-like-isolation-in-django-rest-framework/

using: Django 3.1 Python 3.6

Everything I did including 'The User Messages App' paragraph worked perfectly right before the 'Refactoring the views' passage

and then I got the error when running manage.py runserver

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'saas_django.urls' does not appear to have any pa
tterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import
```

I tried different types of import but I can't figure out where the cirular import happens

My steps to find a bug:

the
saas_django/urls.py refers to user_messages app:

```py
path('api/v1/user-messages/', include('user_messages.urls')),
```

user_messages/urls.py:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [


    path('', views.UserMessageList.as_view(),
        name=views.UserMessageList.name),

    path('<uuid:pk>', views.UserMessageDetail.as_view(),
         name=views.UserMessageDetail.name),

]
```

It seems like something is wrong with the imported user_messages/views.py

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import generics

from . import serializers
from .models import UserMessage


class UserMessageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    name = 'usermessage-list'
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserMessageSerializer
    queryset = UserMessage.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        company_id = user.company_id
        # Added from_user
        serializer.save(company_id=company_id, from_user=user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Changed this to use the UserMessageManager's method
        return UserMessage.objects.get_for_user(self.request.user)


class UserMessageDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    name = 'usermessage-detail'
    permission_classes = (
       permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserMessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Changed this to use the UserMessageManager's method
        return UserMessage.objects.get_for_user(self.request.user)
```

I gues the cause of the error is something about these 2 lines:

```py
from . import serializers
from .models import UserMessage
```

the user_messages/serializers.py also has the import of UserMessages

```py
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework import generics

from . import serializers
from .models import UserMessage


class UserMessageList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    name = 'usermessage-list'
    permission_classes = (
        permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserMessageSerializer
    queryset = UserMessage.objects.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        user = self.request.user
        company_id = user.company_id
        # Added from_user
        serializer.save(company_id=company_id, from_user=user)

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Changed this to use the UserMessageManager's method
        return UserMessage.objects.get_for_user(self.request.user)


class UserMessageDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    name = 'usermessage-detail'
    permission_classes = (
       permissions.IsAuthenticated,
    )
    serializer_class = serializers.UserMessageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        # Changed this to use the UserMessageManager's method
        return UserMessage.objects.get_for_user(self.request.user)
```

I tried to rewrite import as:

```py
from .models import UserMessage as UM
```

but it didn't work.

Project structure is:

```
│   db.sqlite3
│   manage.py
│   sqlite3.exe
│
├───accounts
│      admin.py
│      apps.py
│      models.py
│      serializers.py
│      tests.py
│      urls.py
│      views.py
│      __init__.py
│
├───core
│      models.py
│      serializers.py
│      views.py
│      __init__.py
│
├───saas_django
│      asgi.py
│      settings.py
│      urls.py
│      wsgi.py
│      __init__.py
│
└───user_messages
    │   admin.py
    │   apps.py
    │   models.py
    │   serializers.py
    │   tests.py
    │   urls.py
    │   views.py
    │   __init__.py
    │
    ├───migrations
```

My full code is here: https://github.com/SergSm/test-django-saas/

The question is how to properly debug this type of error?

Comment: use dynamic imports, for eg: import inside the function, tho it's not recommended, but it is the only way to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are few issues in the project itself. There are unresolved references to serializers without which no one will be able to help out. For example:

```
from core.serializers import CompanySafeSerializerMixin
```

This is referenced in a few other serializers. Also, other than this, there is one major issue in the way you have defined the models for:

```
class User(AbstractUser):

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company,
                                related_name='%(class)s',
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                editable=False,
                                default=get_default_company)
```

The default method looks like this:

```
def get_default_company():
    """get or create the non existent company for new users"""

    return Company.objects.get_or_create(is_default_company=True,
                                         name=DEFAULT_COMPANY)[0].pk
```

Not sure in what sequence you made these models but since you have not pushed your migrations onto the VCS, this will cause the issue.

***Remember, always push your migrations on the VCS.***
I cannot highlight this enough. It can lead to serious issues as and when the project grows.

Else, on new setup, Django will never be able to identify correct dependency between models.

Coming to the other problem, since you have used default as method that gets ref from another model, Django will not allow me to make the migrations in the first place since the model itself that its referring to is not yet made.

```
  File "/home/dhwanil/work/packages/test-django-saas/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "companies" does not exist
LINE 1: ...."address", "companies"."is_default_company" FROM "companies...
                                                             ^
```

This would have been solved if lets say you had 0001_initial one with the company model and the 0002_users where you refer the Company model. Also, you might want to look at the concept of **fixtures** that will help you populate a model on every fresh installation.

Coming to the main question you asked, if its indeed a circular, the best way is to closely inspect the traceback, it would show where the circular dep lies. Since I am unable to setup the project until the above mentioned issues are solved, I will not be able to give you a more directed answer.

**Summary:**

1. Always push the migrations that are created after `python manage.py makemigrations` on the VCS, migrations are like commits of the state of your DB, you cannot expect to work with latest state without knowing the steps it was built from.
2. Avoid using methods to get default from another model, the better way is always use fixtures to first populate the DB. Again, this will not be possible without splitting your migrations smartly.

```
return Company.objects.get_or_create(is_default_company=True,
                                         name=DEFAULT_COMPANY)[0].pk
```

3. Alternative to use fixtures would be "Data Migrations", I always recommend to add a custom RunPython code in your migrations to assign defaults. This takes off the overhead of worrying if the data is there in the DB or not, because it will be populated the moment you run `migrate`.
4. Most circular imports can be identified by the traceback, inspect it closely.

That's all for now, if you fix the import issues, let me know. I'll be happy to take a look.

Cheers!

Comment: I didn't include my migrations on purpose. Moreover I really wanted to purge them from git but forgot to do it.
I consider restarting project with all migrations if it's the right way to do it

I created get_default_company() as a part of a logic for new users who want to sign up
It's not just to populate database with data samples. I haven't thought about using fixtures or custom migrations yet
Every new user who signs up must have the default organization

I will restart the project including migrations and refactoring  imports

Comment: I will write here as soon as I fix my import

Comment: Sure, let me know once you do that.

Comment: Well, I made it work. I removed the get_default_company function and fixed a lot of typos. The circular import error is fixed somehow. You may check the new version on github

Comment: @arpa Yess checked. And yeah, this is what I was talking about, using data migrations to populate default and optionally have a reverse function. 